# got problem in tableview in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am reloading the table and my numberOfSections methos is called but the cellForRowAtIndexPath method is not called at that time.When I scroll the tableview then only it is called.Can any suggest me why its happening like this.

Thanks in advance,
Monish.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things I can think of:

1. `tableView:cellForRowAtIndex:` is only called when the cells needs to be displayed. If the cells are not visible then `tableView:cellForRowAtIndex:` will not be called.
2. What is `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` returning? If it's returning `0` then the table view will not call `tableView:cellForRowAtIndex:`.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add some stuff in Benedict answer that is

you also need to impelment `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`

this method.If you implement this method in your code then

It returns `O` object definately thats why your condition arises.